# Regex select inside of function

Tags: regex

here is my code now how can i select the code between the brackets of `x` function with regular expression?

```
 public void x() {
                if (a== null) {
               return;}

               String s = "abc";
               try {
           if (b==1 ) {
            c= null;
               } else {
               d=null;       
               } } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
                    }
                  }
```

result should be

```
 if (a== null) {
         return;}

      String s = "abc";
       try {
       if (b==1 ) {
     c= null;
       } else {
       d=null;       
       } } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e); }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you would probably need a parser here, not a regex.  Regex would do a bad job of figuring out when the function ends.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

using a recursive regex `(?R)` or `(?0)` references the whole regex

```
{([^{}]|(?R))*}
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l5QH1S/3)

and to match only after `public void x()`, `(?1)` referencing the first group.

```
public void x\(\) \K({([^{}]|(?1))*})
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l5QH1S/5)

Following comment to handle the braces inside double quote string

```
{([^{}]|(?R))*}
```

becomes

```
{(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?R))*}
```

and to handle comments

```
{(?:\/(?:\/.*|\*(?:(?!\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/)|"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?R))*}
```

also for single quotes similarly to double quotes will work however a prerequisite is that input is valid C because could match invalid sequence C like `'ab'`.

```
{(?:\/(?:\/.*|\*(?:(?!\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/)|'(?:\\.|[^'])*'|"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?R))*}
```

Comment: What if a [closing curly bracket is placed within a string](https://regex101.com/r/l5QH1S/6) variable?

Comment: it will break but regex can be modified to handle this case

Comment: What if being there within a comment? Can it be fixed too?

Comment: [Not yet](https://regex101.com/r/l5QH1S/9). You have more cases to care about like single quoted strings.

Comment: ok, for the last case there was a typo `"(?:\\.|[^"])*"` instead was wrongly `"(?:\\.|[^"]*)"`

Comment: Now it got better. Did you build this regex specifically for Java codes running from a Java environment?

Comment: to downvoters and those who voted to delete the post, please can you give a comment